# Android manifest: how to specify that ToF sensor (Time of Flight) is required for the app?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, manifest, lidar

I am working on an app that uses the ToF sensor, available only on a few devices. So I want my app to be available on Google Play only to compatible device (those that have a ToF sensor).

How can I do that ?

Thanks !